# Checking and creating directory

Tags: c, create-directory

I want to check and then create a dir if it does not already exists.

I used the following code:

```
#define APP_DATA_DIR_CHILD_2  "./child2"

g_nResult = GetFileAttributes((wchar_t*)APP_DATA_DIR_CHILD_2);
if (g_nResult <= 0)
{
    g_nResult = mkdir(APP_DATA_DIR_CHILD_2);
}
```

But is is not checking properly. I get -1 returned in `GetFileAttributes()` even after the directory has been created.

Could someone please help?

PS: I would also like to make sure that the code works on both Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
#define APP_DATA_DIR_CHILD_2                    "./child2"
g_nResult = GetFileAttributes((wchar_t*)APP_DATA_DIR_CHILD_2);
```

By (if Unicode is defined)

```
#define APP_DATA_DIR_CHILD_2                    L"./child2"
g_nResult = GetFileAttributes(APP_DATA_DIR_CHILD_2);
```

Your code is far away of portable... Use stat instead

```
struct stat sts;
if ( stat(APP_DATA_DIR_CHILD_2, &sts) != 0) {
    // Fail to get info about the file, may not exist...
}
else {
    if (S_ISDIR(sts.st_mode)) {  /* The file is a directory... */ }
}
```

Take a look at the documentation : http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat

Comment: could you please explain how i would use stat, so that i could make my code portable. Also, with the above mentioned change i get the following warning:
warning C4133: 'function' : incompatible types - from 'unsigned short [9]' to 'const char *'

Comment: Hold on i just checked and GetFileAttributes() works on llinux as well. So how is my code not portable?

Comment: @Sunny Where did you find this ? Which include ? This function is not defined in any of the .h of my Linux box... And I cannot find any documentation...

Comment: MY bad i was looking at something else.